# Jquery, height is not a function

Tags: jquery, height

I am trying to get the final height of a div this way:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var cards = $(".card-group > .col-md-2");
  for(a=0; a< cards.length; a++){
    console.log(cards[a].height());
  }
});
```

and I get this error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: cards[a].height is not a function TypeError: cards[a].height is not a function

Everything seems to be fine and when I output just: `console.log(cards[a])` it prints out the element as it should but when it comes to height I have this problem so jquery is included.

PS: I have already searched the net and stackoverflow. Similar questions are in different context and didn't help me. Most of them were either mistype or didn't include jquery file at all

Comment: Put that in jquery object wrapper. `$(cards[a])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cards[a]` is the same as `cards.get(a)`. Both return the DOM node at the given index (which has no `.height()` method).

> The [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each
>   jQuery object. If the value of index is out of bounds — less than the
>   negative number of elements or equal to or greater than the number of
>   elements — it returns `undefined`.

You can use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)
>   method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that
>   set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the
>   set.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cards = $(".card-group > .col-md-2");

    for (a = 0; a < cards.length; a++) {
        console.log(cards.eq(a).height());
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cards = $(".card-group > .col-md-2");

  for (a = 0; a < cards.length; a++) {
    console.log(cards.eq(a).height());
  }
});
```

```css
.card-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-md-2 {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </div>
</div>
```

Or with [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of an explicit loop

> The [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword `this` refers to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cards = $(".card-group > .col-md-2");

    cards.each(function() {
        var card = $(this);
        console.log(card.height());
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cards = $(".card-group > .col-md-2");

  cards.each(function() {
    var card = $(this);
    console.log(card.height());
  });
});
```

```css
.card-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-md-2 {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
    nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </div>
</div>
```